# How to take MySQL table to JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a MySQL table which I'd like to put into JSON format as shown below, but I'm struggling how to do it. The purpose of this is I have a product catalogue with 3 levels of categorisation, which I need to create a drop down menu for.

Can someone help please?

**Menu I want to end up creating**

```
a         <- Level 1
- a1      <- Level 2
- - a11   <- Level 3
- - a12
- - a13
- a2
- - a21
- - a22
- - a23
- a3
- - a31
- - a32
- - a33
b
- b1
- - b11
- - b12
- - b13
- b2
- - b21
- - b22
- - b23
c
- c1
- c2
- c3
d
e
```

**MySQL table**

```
f   b   t
-------------------
a   a1  a11
a   a1  a12
a   a1  a13
a   a2  a21
a   a2  a22
a   a2  a23
a   a3  a31
a   a3  a32
a   a3  a33
b   b1  b11
b   b1  b12
b   b1  b13
b   b2  b21
b   b2  b22
b   b2  b23
c   c1
c   c2
c   c3
d
e
```

**JSON I want to end up with, so I can crete the menu**

```
{"menu":{"items":[{"value":"a","items":[{"value":"a1","items":["a11","a12","a13"]},{"value":"a2","items":["a21","a22","a23"]},{"value":"a3","items":["a31","a32","a33"]}]},{"value":"b","items":[{"value":"b1","items":["b11","b12","b13"]},{"value":"b2","items":["b21","b22","b23"]}]},{"value":"c","items":[{"value":"c1"},{"value":"c2"},{"value":"c3"}]},{"value":"d"},{"value":"e"}]}}
```

Comment: for the sql side look at this http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: Seems like you need a [closure table](http://karwin.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html) to store hierarchical data in MySQL and a recursive function to build the multidimensional array that you will then `json_encode()`

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a nifty little function called [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

> **json_encode** — Returns the JSON representation of a value

All you have to do is extract your data into a normal PHP array and then pass it through this function.

```
$orig = array(
 'stack' => 'overflow'
);

$jsonString = json_encode($orig);
// {"stack":"overflow"}
```

Comment: To the OP, you'll obviously need to do a loop to create a multidimensional array before json_encoding.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that is what I had to do, but creating the multidimensional array is a headache for me and was hoping someone might be able to supply some code. Cheeky me I know ;)